# How to make images replace each other with a button?

Tags: javascript, html

So, I'm trying to develop a sort of visual novel, and I'm trying to make a code to replace other images when a specific image appears, (for example, if "happy" is onscreen i want "sad" to be hidden so the pictures don't overlap eachother)
Here's my code:

```
<style>
section {
  display: none;
}

.d-block {
  display: block;
}
</style>
<section class="d-block">Horace</section>
<section>Ursa</section>
<section><img id=sad src=https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20220716/ourmid/pngtree-banana-yellow-fruit-banana-skewers-png-image_5944324.png></section>
<section><img id=neutral src=https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/banana-bunch-five-600nw-1057197824.jpg></section>
<section><img id=happy src=https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/05/65/93/25/360_F_565932566_6bll77MbikvLen4pPoLVvlrqmvKTZ7Nw.jpg></section>
<section>Thus</section>

<button>Next</button>
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
const TextShower = document.querySelector('button');
TextShower.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let hidden_section = document.querySelector('section:not(.d-block)');
  if (hidden_section != null) {
    hidden_section.classList.add('d-block');
  } else {
    TextShower.disabled = true;
    }
  });
  const Happy = document.getElementById("happy")
  if (happy.hasAttribute("d-block")) {
  document.getElementById("sad","neutral").removeAttribute("d-block")
        }
  });
    </script>
```

```
  const Happy = document.getElementById("happy")
  if (happy.hasAttribute("d-block")) {
  document.getElementById("sad","neutral").removeAttribute("d-block")
        }
  });
```

this is the if statement i tried to create to replace the portraits. did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to the answer is to define an index,and to increase it when clicking the button, if encounter the current section and the previous section both have img,then hide the previous one, if there is no next section disable the button.

```html
<style>
  section {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .d-block {
    display: block;
  }
</style>
<section class="d-block">Horace</section>
<section>Ursa</section>
<section><img id=sad src=https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20220716/ourmid/pngtree-banana-yellow-fruit-banana-skewers-png-image_5944324.png>
</section>
<section><img id=neutral src=https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/banana-bunch-five-600nw-1057197824.jpg>
</section>
<section><img id=happy src=https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/05/65/93/25/360_F_565932566_6bll77MbikvLen4pPoLVvlrqmvKTZ7Nw.jpg></section>
<section>Thus</section>
<button>Next</button>
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    let index = 1
    const button = document.querySelector('button');
    const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
      if (sections[index]) {
        if (hasImg(index) && hasImg(index - 1)) {
          sections[index - 1].classList.remove("d-block")
        }
        sections[index].classList.add("d-block")
      }
      if (!sections[++index]) { //there is no next section disable the button
        button.disabled = true;
      }
    });

    function hasImg(index) {
      return sections[index].querySelector('img')
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (hidden_section.querySelector('img#happy')) {
    document.getElementById("sad").classList.remove('d-block');
    document.getElementById("neutral").classList.remove('d-block');
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code answers the question will make it more useful for others in the future. Please consider updating your answer with some explanatory notes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So if I get the question right you are trying to show one image at a time on button click [If "happy" shown hide the "sad/neutral" or vice versa.]

**NOTE:** You can run the code in the codePen for the quick verification and it work just fine.

Here's how you can do it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,  initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Visual Novel</title>
<style>
  section img {
    display: none;
  }
  .active img {
    display: block;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<-- Images -->
<section><img id="sad" src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20220716/ourmid/pngtree-banana-yellow-fruit-banana-skewers-png-image_5944324.png"></section>
<section><img id="neutral" src="https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/banana-bunch-five-600nw-1057197824.jpg"></section>
<section class="active"><img id="happy" src="https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/05/65/93/25/360_F_565932566_6bll77MbikvLen4pPoLVvlrqmvKTZ7Nw.jpg"></section>

<button id="nextButton">Next</button>

<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const images = document.querySelectorAll('section');
    let currentIndex = 0;
 const nextButton = document.getElementById('nextButton');
    nextButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      // Hide the current image
      images[currentIndex].classList.remove('active');
      
      // Increment index or loop back to the first image
      currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % images.length;

      // Show the next image
      images[currentIndex].classList.add('active');
    });
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

If you want to undertsand what happend here you go:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Image Toggle</title>
<style>
  section img {
    display: none;
  }
  .active img {
    display: block;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
```

- Defined a `title` for the page in the `head`  section.
- Inside the `<style>` tag in the `<head>` section, we define CSS rules for styling the image.
- a. `display:none` for images inside the `section` hide the images by-default.
- b. Define a class `.active` that makes images visible as `display:block`.

**NOTE** Happy image have the `.active` class for now.

```
<section class="active"><img id="sad" src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20220716/ourmid/pngtree-banana-yellow-fruit-banana-skewers-png-image_5944324.png"></section>
<section><img id="neutral" src="https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/banana-bunch-five-600nw-1057197824.jpg"></section>
<section><img id="happy" src="https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/05/65/93/25/360_F_565932566_6bll77MbikvLen4pPoLVvlrqmvKTZ7Nw.jpg"></section>
```

- Each image inside the `section` with the `sad` and `neutral` being hidden by default.
- `Happy` image have the class `.active` hence its displayed.

```
<button id="nextButton">Next</button>
```

- When clicked on button we will toggle between the images.

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const images = document.querySelectorAll('section');
    let currentIndex = 0;

    const nextButton = document.getElementById('nextButton');
    nextButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      // Hide the current image
      images[currentIndex].classList.remove('active');
      
      // Increment index or loop back to the first image
      currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % images.length;

      // Show the next image
      images[currentIndex].classList.add('active');
    });
  });
</script>
```

- When the DOM content is loaded `DOMContentLoaded`,we execute code inside the callback function.
- We select all `section` and store them inside the `images` variable.
- We initialized a variable `currentIndex` to keep track of the currently active image.
- We clicked on `next button` add the event listener for `click` event.
- Button clicked:

  - a. We remove the `.active` class from the currently active image ["happy"], hiding it.
  - b. We increment the `currentIndex`.
  - c. We add the `.active` class to the next image, making it visible.

This way, clicking the button toggles between the images, showing only one image at a time. The images cycle through in a loop, so after reaching the last image, clicking the button will show the first image again.

**NOTE** -- its better to have the `toggleClass` rather than adding or removing class separately or based on attribute add or remove class.

Integrate the answer and have the logic work for your own code.

Keep Learning and keep exploring.

Happy Coding and have a good day❤️.